# Any way to run JS after swf is finished playing?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flash

I'm working on a project where a SWF will play (as sort of a splash), followed by JS. After the video plays, the navigation and content will appear, and the video will fade out. I'm just wondering what would be the best way to accomplish this? Play the video first and then load everything via ajax behind the scenes? The goal is to be as seamless as possible and I am having a flash asset provided to me by the client. I have zero experience with flash outside of simply embedding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flash asset can call a JavaScript method via `ExternalInterface` when it's done.

However, the use of Flash for splash screens is something generally hated by users.  I would recommend against it unless it's an intro they specifically click a "Show Intro" button to show (as opposed to always showing with a Skip Intro to skip).

Comment: I completely agree, I usually try to stay away from flash if possible (it explains my lack of knowledge with it) but the video is only about 5-10 seconds and it's just for effect.

Thanks for the prompt reply and I will try this out as soon as possible.